# sprite kit - Sprite randomly drifting upwards after rotation

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

For the sake of simplicity, the scene has a circle sprite and a square sprite.  The square sprite is the child of an SKNode that follows around the circle sprite so that rotation of the square always happens around the circle.  However, when the node is rotated, the square randomly drifts upwards.  This behavior stops once the rotation makes its way all the way around.  Here is the code:

```
_square = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"square"]; 
_circle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"circle"];
_circle.position = CGPointMake(-200, 300);
[self addChild:_circle];
_rotateNode = [SKNode node];
_rotateNode.position = CGPointMake(300, 300);
[self addChild:_rotateNode];
[_rotateNode addChild:_square];


SKAction *moveBall = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(1200, 300) duration:12];
[_circle runAction:moveBall];

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
SKAction *rotate = [SKAction rotateByAngle:-M_PI_2 duration:0.2];
[_rotateNode runAction:rotate];
```

}

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

_rotateNode.position = _circle.position;
double xOffset = (300 -_circle.position.x);
double yOffset = (300 - _circle.position.y);
_square.position = CGPointMake(xOffset, yOffset);
```

}

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: That code doesn't look like it would compile, since you are adding a CGPoint as a child to self. Do you have a typo on line 3 where you assign _circle a second time?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you are asking why the square moves in unexpected ways? The circle is moving, but on every frame you are setting the rotateNode's position to be the same as the circle, and they both have the same parent: self, so we can ignore circle for any debugging because it just executes its action every frame to get a new position.

The oddness, most likely, comes in because you are manually repositioning rotateNode, which would then move all of its children, including square. But in every frame you are also repositioning square manually. So rotateNode rotates, changes the position of square because it rotated, and then you reposition square to have a fixed offset. Further complicated depending on whether your goal is to position the square in world space or in parent space. But it's not clear what your goal is there.